# Cannot send session cache limiter, what am i missing?

Tags: php, session

can someone please tell me what Im missing? this simple script

```
<?
session_start();
?>
```

displays the following error message:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\index.php:1) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\index.php on line 2
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a Byte Order Mark generated by your text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Check if there are any whitespaces before `<?`
If there is any output before `session_start()` - it will not work

Comment: +1.  Specifically, check line one of C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\index.php as indicated by the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`session_start();` should be the first thing on  your page. Before any text, or spaces. Nothing should precede it in your page.

```
<?php

  session_start();

  /* code here */

?>
```